# Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis Exercise 3.4 (c)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory

Here is the problem:

*Suppose* $f$ *is a complex measurable function on* $X$, $\mu$ *is a positive measure on* $x$, *and* $\phi(p) = \int_X |f|^p \, d\mu$, $0<p<\infty$. *Let* $E = \{p: \phi(p)<\infty\}$. *Assume* $||f||_\infty >0$.

*is E necessarily Closed? Open? Can E be a single point? Can E be any Connected subset of* $(o,\infty)$ ?

I know that $\phi$ is convex and thus continuous on the interior of E, and that E is a connected subset of $(0, \infty)$. from a couple of simple examples, it seems to me that E must be an open interval although I'm not sure and I can not prove it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take $X=(0,1)$ and $f(x)=1/x$, then $E=(0,1)$, so $E$ is not necessarily closed.

Actually, take $(a,b) \subset (0,+\infty)$, $X=(0,+\infty)$, $f(x)=1/x^{1/b}$ for $x<1$ and $f(x)=1/x^{1/a}$ for $x>1$. Then $E=(a,b)$. (Riemann's integrals)

If you take $X=(2,+\infty)$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{t \ln^2 (t)}$, then $E=[1,+\infty)$, so $E$ is not necessarily open.

Actually, take $[a,b] \subset (0,+\infty)$, $X=(0,+\infty)$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{t^{1/b} \mid \ln(t) \mid ^{2/b}}$ for $x<1$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{t^{1/a}\ln^{2/a}(t)}$ for $x>2$. Then $E=[a,b]$. (these are known as Bertand's integrals/series in french - I don't know their names in english)

You can show the same way that $[a,b)$ and $(a,b]$ can be realized as a set $E$.

Comment: Very well done, AlexL !